Using Python from the QGIS installation without opening QGIS itself
I have a Python script that should be started via a batch file, Using Python from the QGIS installation without opening QGIS itself. Unfortunately this doesn't work because I think the Python installation of QGIS accesses the PyQt libraries differently.
What do I have to do so that the script still works via a batch via the QGIS Python installation?
The attached scripts work without any problems on another system that has Python (and PyQt) installed directly. The script without PyQt library also runs via QGIS-Python and Batch.
I use QGIS 3.16 with Python 3.7 and Windows 10 However, installing an “additional” Python version on the system is not an option.
_test.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class TEST(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        global counter
        super(TEST, self).__init__() 
        uic.loadUi(r'C:\_testdruck.ui', self) 
        counter = 1

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_ButtonSchliessen_clicked(self):
        self.close()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_ButtonZeigen_clicked(self):
        global counter
        self.lineEdit_zeigen.setText(f"Wurde {str(counter)} mal gedrückt")
        counter += 1    

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TEST()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

_test_2.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
import subprocess

ergebnissdatei = open(r'C:\test.txt','w')
ergebnissdatei.write("\n  --> \n Das ist ein TEST!!!")
ergebnissdatei.close()
 
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe C:\test.txt')

and the Batchfiles:
@echo off

"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37\python.exe" "C:\_test.py"

echo    Beliebige Taste zum beenden
pause > NUL
exit

@echo off

"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37\python.exe" "C:\_test_2.py"

echo    Beliebige Taste zum beenden
pause > NUL
exit

Error running _test.cmd
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:_test.py", line 4, in from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
_testdruck.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="ButtonZeigen">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>200</x>
     <y>230</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Zeigen</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="ButtonSchliessen">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>300</x>
     <y>230</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Schließen</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_zeigen">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>110</x>
     <y>150</y>
     <width>191</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>



If you have QGis installed then you have python installed

I know that Python is included with the QGIS installation.
That's the reason for my question.
I want to run a GUI over this Python installation, without Pugin or exe. But somewhere there's something wrong with my approach.
